# How to insert a string as a new line in current buffer using elisp

Tags: elisp

There are insert function, but no insert-line function. What I need is to insert a line like "commit;" every 1000 lines in the current buffer. So I need to loop and then need some function like

```
(insert-line 1000 "commit;")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very basic version:

```
(defun insert-lines (skip text)
  "Insert `text' every `skip' lines."
  (while (zerop (forward-line skip))
    (insert text)))
```

You can use it with <kbd>M-: (insert-lines 10 "commit;\n") RET</kbd>.

You can add bells and whistles yourself, like [`interactive`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) and [`save-excursion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002dexcursion.html).